# strtotime for Emacs Lisp

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp, strtotime

Is there any functionality in Emacs Lisp that behaves similar to [PHP's `strtotime` function](http://php.net/strtotime)? (Actually AFAIK it implements [relative items of the GNU date input formats](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Relative-items-in-date-strings.html#SEC120).)

In PHP I can write

```
echo strtotime("+2 months"); //1258891352
echo strtotime("-3 months +2 weeks"); //1246952239
```

which return the corresponding UNIX timestamps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not exactly what you're asking for, this may be of use.  There's a command `'org-schedule` in the package [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) that has a really nice interface to choosing dates.  The specific command that does it is [`'org-read-date`](http://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html), which understands many ways of representing the date, including:

```
 +0            --> today
 .             --> today
 +4d           --> four days from today
 +4            --> same as above
 +2w           --> two weeks from today
 ++5           --> five days from default date
 +2tue         --> second Tuesday from now.
```

If you're looking for an interactive way to specify dates with that handy syntactic sugar, that routine should fit the bill nicely.  If you're looking for a programmatic solution, it looks as though the above command calls `'org-read-date-analyze` to do the leg work.  Note: its usage is a little obscure (two of its arguments are never defined...), so if you can't figure it out directly, it might be worth sending mail to the [org mailing list](http://news.gmane.org/gmane.emacs.orgmode).

Comment: A checked org-mode's date facilities but didn't find this function. Thanks.

Comment: The function `org-read-date-analyze isn't a command, but is defined in org.el around line 13155 (for latest org.el: http://repo.or.cz/w/org-mode.git/blob/HEAD:/lisp/org.el)

Comment: I accept this answer. It does not cover exactly the same functionality what `strtotime` provides, but its goal is similar and is a native solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun string-to-time (date)
  (shell-command-to-string (format "date --date='%s' +%%s" date)))
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest inbuilt function I know of is encode-time. If you want to use natural language, you'll probably have to end up writing something like this: http://github.com/chaitanyagupta/chronicity